# Align rotated text to left of canvas

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, chart.js

I am trying to add a rotated Y axis title (SPEED (MPH)) to my chart. It simple doesn't align to where I want which is to the far left as pointed out in the image. Have tried to mess with positions and margins. I either ends up shifting the chart canvas below the label or the chart canvas moves out of the blue box. Also using Bootstrap grid system in this instance. Any advice please. Thanks.

[image]

```
<! -- html -->
<div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="k-livestat_box">
                <h3>Speed Status</h3>
                <hr>
                <div class="radar-chart-sz">
                    <!--Line Speed Chart -->
                    <label class="ylabel">Speed ( mph )</label>
                    <canvas id="lineChart"></canvas>
                </div>
                <h4 id="currentspeed">Current Speed ( mph ): 100</h4>
                <h4 id="topspeed">Highest Speed ( mph ): 100</h4>
                <h4 id="lowspeed">Lowest Speed ( mph ): 100</h4>
                <h4 id="avgspeed">Average Speed ( mph ): 100</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
```

..

```
/*CSS*/

.ylabel {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}​

.radar-chart-sz{
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.k-livestat_box {
    margin: 15px 2.5px;
    padding: 25px;
    min-height: 458px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: #1A284B;
    color: #C3CF01;
    border: 1px solid #162444;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add in a transform-origin and then a translate for adjusting

```
  ...
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(-25%, -50%);
}
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kyt3Lmyc/